# Key Down event handler C#

Tags: c#, event-handling, trackbar

I am currently working on a Maze Game in C# using Visual Studio Windows Forms and have encounter an issue.

Basically what I want to do is to use the arrow keys to control the movement of my pacman character. I have created a switch statement as follows:

```
private void Maze_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
            pac.PacmanImageLeft();
            pac.xPosition -= 5;
            break;
        case Keys.Right:
            pac.PacmanImageRight();
            pac.xPosition += 5;
            break;
        case Keys.Up:
            pac.PacmanImageUp();
            pac.yPosition -= 5;
            break;
        case Keys.Down:
            pac.PacmanImageDown();
            pac.yPosition += 5;
            break;       
    }
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I noticed that the above code works only when I insert a Track Bar on my form. Does anyone know what is going on? why is this happening and what should I do to fix this?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) the event only "Occurs when a key is pressed while the control has focus.".  Can you confirm that whatever control this event is bound to has focus when you are testing?

Comment: To be honest I'm not so sure anymore, on my form I have two panels the first panel is the one which displays the game. The second panel is below that and it contains buttons like: start, stop.

Comment: maybe experiment by registering a keydown event on different controls until you find some consistency

Comment: It also only happens in the first key press, it doesn't repeat until you let up and press again.